# How to change DIalog window size Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to implement an activity with a `dialog` theme.
My `manifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".activity.AddShow"
android:theme="@style/CustomDialog">
```

The problem is that I want to increase the dialog `width`. How can I achieve this?
I tried with:
`styles.xml`

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

But I have this problem at bottom and top:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, easy solution:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">99%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">99%</item>
</style>
```